# MS Access: Нумерация в запросах

Tags: sql, ms-access

Нужно сделать нумерацию в запросах, она просто должна выводиться независимо от других данных.
Пример кода, который тут особо и не нужен

```
    SELECT Left([ФИО],InStr([ФИО]," ")-1) AS f,  
     Mid([ФИО],InStr([ФИО],"")+1,InStrRev([ФИО]," ")-InStr([ФИО]," ")-1) AS i, 
     Mid([ФИО],InStrRev([ФИО]," ")+1) AS o
     FROM ["Администрация"]
```

;

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34588198/5045688

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17279320/4928642